# How to setup Mail.app to automatically reply with the recipient account / the account that received the email, not default account

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

I have multiple accounts set up in my Mail.app, all linked to my personal contact card.

Let's say A is my default email account. If I compose a new topic with a new email, A is automatically selecting as sender. Then, I change it to B with the drop down list. Send. Then later, I got a reply. If I tap reply, A is selected automatically.

Is it possible to make it that it would be B?

Apple, that would be much much more logical... Plus, it would prevent me from sending emails as A when it should be as B. Indeed, my contact name appears in the From: field, so if I don't think about changing it, I won't see it is not the email account I want to use...